# MSVCR110.dll missing on Win 8.1 needed for TIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe2, windows-8.1, idhttp

In Delphi XE2, I use Indy TIdHTTP to make a http connection. In Windows 7 it works perfectly. But now I have started the program on a Windows 8.1 computer and when trying to connect (which in Windows 7 works perfectly) I get an error message from Windows telling me that **MSVCR110.dll** is missing on the computer (message title: "**Drag: MyProgram.exe - System error**").

Is it safe to take the **MSVCR110.dll** from my Windows 7 computer and install it on the Windows 8.1 computer in my application's directory? Do I have to somehow register the DLL when I install it in Windows 8.1 in my application's directory?

EDIT 201407152319: Ahhhh, found the culprit: This error occurs only in Windows 8.1 when using the new (version 1.0.1.7) (heart-bleed-tested) **libeay32.dll** and **ssleay32.dll**! When using the older DLLs in Windows 8.1 the error does not occur!

Comment: Both answers are equally correct and helpful. I'm not sure which one I should check.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it seems that I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to know how to meet the dependency but it seems you wanted to know how to remove it.

Comment: I reverted your edit. You were obviously keen to solve your problem, but Q&A is about answering questions. If you want to edit the question to ask how to remove the dependency that would fit much better with the answer that you accepted. I suggest that you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indy has no dependencies on the VC++ runtime library.  However, some distributions of the OpenSSL DLLs do.  The OpenSSL DLLs that are available on Indy's [Fulgan mirror](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) have been compiled without the dependency.

Comment: That means they have two runtime, one each, which seems wasteful

Comment: Perhaps, but a lot of people don't like the dependency.  Indy doesn't care one way or the other, use whatever OpenSSL DLLs you want. You don't have to use the Fulgan DLLs. They are provided as a convenience, not a requirement.

Comment: Mhmm, the Fulgan "openssl-1.0.1h-i386-win32.zip" also works in Windows 7 x64, despite the "win32" in the name of the archive. But the Fulgan "openssl-1.0.1h-x64_86-win64.zip" does not work in Windows 8 32 bit. So I assume I should install the DLLs from "openssl-1.0.1h-i386-win32.zip" both in Windows 7/8/8.1 and in both 32/64 bit versions?

Comment: Does anybody know whether the Fulgan DLLs ar heartbleed-tested?

Comment: It does not matter whether the OS is 32bit/64bit, it matters whether your app is 32bit/64bit.  If your app is 32bit, you MUST use the 32bit DLLs. If your app is 64bit, you MUST use the 64bit DLLs.

Comment: The Fulgan DLLs are compiled from the official OpenSSL codebase. Fulgan's latest DLLs have been compiled using a heartbleed-fixed version of the OpenSSL codebase.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks Remy, these are very clear and concise answers (also the answers from David).

Comment: @RemyLebeau So the "win32" and "win64" substrings in the archive names are potentially misleading?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57357/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-user1580348).

Comment: @iuser They are not at all misleading